Amazon Managed Airflow (MWAA) An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) after working for a period of time
I have tried a couple of times to get a complex data transfer process working on MWAA with different sized instances.
The DAG has 500+ tasks, and works as intended when first setup. However, after a period of time I then get the following error:
*** Unable to read remote logs from Cloudwatch XXXXXXXXXXX
*** An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetLogEvents operation: The specified log stream does not exist.

For smaller instances, the problem occurs after just over a week, for larger instances, the problem surfaces later (2 months).
I have added in lines to tasks to report on memory and disc usages, and everything seems to be stable for each day, suggesting everything is cleared correctly after each task. I am not sure what else there could be that is consuming some resource that prevents even the most basic task from completing, or at least being logged as completing.

I am running into same problem. Seem related to to space on instace. I see "[Errno 28] No space left on device: \'/usr/local/airflow/logs/dag_id=.." on worker log group. For me restarting instances / by making any update on mwaa would fix the problem.
